# Limit CPU and memory usage for PHP-FPM and Nginx processes in CentOS

Tags: memory, cpu, resources

I want to limit CPU and memory  usage for PHP-FPM and Nginx processes in CentOS.
I came across following tools

- cpulimit
- cggroups
- memory resource locater

which will more efficient and how can I configure for limiting resources for PHP-FPM and Nginx processes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think "cpulimit" is best way to control cpu usage per process. cpulimit does not act on the nice value or other scheduling priority stuff, but on the real cpu usage.

#### cpulimit

Install `cpulimit` on Linux:

```
yum install cpulimit
```

To limit CPU usage of the process called nginx to 40%, enter:

```
cpulimit -e nginx -l 40
```

To limit CPU usage of the process to 40% by using its PID, enter:

```
cpulimit -p 3302 -l 40
```

Where,

-p : Process PID.
-e : Process name.
-l : percentage of CPU allowed from 0 to 100.
-P: absolute path name of the executable program file.